# Using std::bind with std::visit

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, stdbind

I'm trying to use `std::bind` together with `std::visit` in order to get a function where the visitor is bound.

I'm getting a "no instance of overloaded function" but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong with regards to bind.

How do I utilize `std::bind` to capture the visitor?

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using Somenum = std::variant<uint64_t, double>;

struct Visitor {
    uint64_t operator()(const uint64_t& num) const {
        return num;
    }
    uint64_t operator()(const double& num) const{
        return 5;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const Somenum a = 3.0;
    const Somenum b = (uint64_t)6;
    const Visitor v{};
    const auto f = std::bind(std::visit<Visitor, Somenum>, v, std::placeholders::_1);
    const auto f2 = [&v](Somenum x) {
        return std::visit(v, x);
    };

    std::cout << f(a) << std::endl << f(b)<< std::endl;

    std::cout << f2(a) << std::endl << f2(b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Effectively I'd like `f` and `f2` to have the same behavior

Removing the line where `f` is called allows everything to compile.

Comment: Don't use need to do `std::get<uint64_t>(s)` to get the value, somewhere?
  And perhaps `std::holds_alternative<uint64_t>(s)` to check if the variant holds that type, perhaps?  Likewise with `double`.

Comment: Don't think so. Where should I do that?

std::visit is supposed to handle that I think.

Comment: Why do you even want to use `std::bind` here instead of the lambda? You're mixing the latest hotness of C++1z with the clunky old stuff that helped show the need for lambdas in the language in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't explain the `<unresolved overloaded function type>` error - but what you're doing is incorrect anyway. `std::visit` takes a bunch of forwarding references, so `std::visit<Visitor, Somenum>` is a function pointer whose type is something like:

```
decltype(auto)(*)(Visitor&&, Somenum&&);
```

Those are rvalue references. But you're not actually invoking this function with rvalues, you're invoking it with lvalues. const lvalues even. So the version you want is really `std::visit<Visitor const&, Somenum const&>`. This works:

```
auto p = std::visit<Visitor const&, Somenum const&>;
const auto f = std::bind(p, v, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Again I'm not sure why you need to pre-declare `p`.

---

This should hopefully make it clear why using the lambda is strongly preferred. You don't have to manually before template argument deduction just to get it right!